# Galois extension preserves irreducibility

Tags: galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Consider a Galois extension $K/F$. Let $f\in F[x]$ be irreducible of prime degree. If $f$ has no roots in $K$, prove that $f$ is irreducible in $K[x]$.

Comment: What if the extension is not assumed to be Galois ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will show that if $f$ is reducible in $K[x]$ then it has a root in $K$.

Let $p(x)\in K[x]$ be a irreducubla over $K[x]$ and $p(x)\mid f(x)$.

Let $\sigma\in Aut(K/F)$ then $\sigma(p(x))\mid \sigma (f(x))=f(x)$ set $r(x)=\sigma_0(p(x))\sigma_1(p(x))...\sigma_k(p(x))$ such that we takes all different $\sigma(p(x))$.

Notice that $\sigma(r(x))=r(x) \ \ for \ \ all \ \ \sigma\in Aut(K/F) \implies r(x)\in F(x)$ and $r(x)\mid f(x)$ and $f$ is irreducable so $r(x)=f(x)$.

Now let $\deg(p(x))=n$ since $\deg(p(x)=\deg(\sigma_i(p(x)))\implies \deg(r(x))=\deg(f(x))=kn$ but since $\deg(f(x))$ is prime we must have $n=1$ so $f$ has a root in $K$.

Comment: Can you justify why $r(x) \ | \ f(x)$?

Comment: @pre-kidney: since $p(x)$ is irreducable, $\sigma(p(x))$ is also irreducable and 
if different irreducable divides a polynomial so is their product divides it.

Comment: What happens if $f(x)$ is irreducible but not separable, for instance $f(x)=p(x)^2$? Then your product over the conjugates of $p(x)$ would just be $p(x)$.

Comment: @pre-kidney: in that case, $r(x)=p(x)$ but we showed that $r(x)\in F[x]$ (by using it is galois extension) but this is not possible as 
$f(x)$ is irreducable.(This case can not happen)

Comment: Thanks for answering my questions. The reason I am asking is because I am worried you are implicitly assuming that the base field is perfect.

Comment: you are welcome, if is there any point , you can ask freely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15998/discussion-between-pre-kidney-and-mesel).

Answer (score 2):

Here is another proof which may be longer but perhaps is more conceptual.
It uses several lemmas:

*Lemma 1.* If $E/F$ is a field extension of prime degree, then it has no proper subextensions.

Pf. If $F\subseteq E'\subseteq E$, then $[E:E']$ divides the prime number $[E:F]$, so either $[E:E']=1$ and $E=E'$ or $[E:E']=[E:F]$ and $F=E$.

*Lemma 2.* If $K/F$ is Galois and if $E/F$ is a field extension, then $KE/E$ is Galois, and the restriction-of-automorphism map induces an isomorphism $Gal(KE/E)\cong Gal(K/E\cap K)$.

The proof is standard, e.g it appears in Lang's *Algebra*, hence I omit it.

*Corollary 3.* If $K/F$ is Galois and $E/F$ is of prime degree, then either $E\subseteq K$ or $[KE:E]=[K:F]$.

Pf. By Lemma 2, $Gal(KE/E) \cong Gal(K/E\cap K)$, so $[KE:E]=[K:E\cap K]$. By Lemma 1, either $E\cap K = F$ and then $[KE:E]=[K:F]$ or $E\cap K = E$ and then $E\subseteq K$.

Now answering the question: Apply Cor. 3 to $E=F(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$. Then either $E\subseteq K$ or $[EK:K]=[E:K]=\deg f$. The former contradicts the assumption that $\alpha\not\in K$ and the latter implies that $f$ is irreducible over $K$, since $EK=K(\alpha)$. QED